# Basic anagram function

Tags: javascript

Hi this is probably an easy question. So I want to make a basic anagram function in Javascript.

The following snippet does not work

```
anagrams = (phraseOne, phraseTwo) => {
    if (phraseOne.split("").sort() === phraseTwo.split("").sort()) {
        return true  
    } else {
        return false
    } 
}
```

However this does work

```
anagrams = (phraseOne, phraseTwo) => {
    if (phraseOne.split("").sort().join("") === phraseTwo.split("").sort().join("")) {
        return true  
    } else {
        return false
    } 
}
```

Why? The arrays are identical before you join("") them

Comment: Can you give which inputs pass the first snippet but not the second one?

Comment: @sp00m every given input.

Comment: `.join` will convert the array back to the same string

Comment: @JonasWilms Oh, I read the question the opposite way, I thought #1 was passing and #2 failing ;) So yeah, duplicates the one you linked.

Comment: The `==` operator for Objects in Javascript only checks to see if the objects are the same actual object reference, not if they are two separate object that contain the same contents. According to the [chart](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) `[] == []` gives us false. So the second `anagram` works because it compares strings rather than objects.

Answer (score 1):

That's because strings are compared by value and arrays are compared by reference in JS. You can find out more about comparison here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness